# How do I access the following nested property of a large object?

Tags: javascript

`console.log(mustaccessthis)`

returns:

```
Element {
  sessionId: 'cca3f23e-2dac-46ef-8b00-7b644475b861',
  elementId: '77d27a45-4b88-45b5-8843-0f1833d64387',
  'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '77d27a45-4b88-45b5-8843-0f1833d64387',
  selector: ".//*",
  index: 0,
  emit: [Function: bound ],
  addCommand: [Function] }
```

I am trying to access the `elementId`, here is what I have tried:

- `mustaccessthis.elementId`
- `mustaccessthis.Element.elementId`
- `mustaccessthis.Element.elementId`
- `mustaccessthis[0].elementId`

None of these are returning the value.

How would I grab that `elementId` value for comparisons etc?

Error returned is nearly always

> "Cannot read property 'elementId' of undefined"

Comment: what is the error you are getting and please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Try mustaccessthis[0].elementId, JSON objects are usually parsed in a loop

Comment: Can you add more details than just your console log? Will help debug

Comment: @MladenSkrbic Where is the string that has no key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

```
 mustaccessthis['elementId']
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

<strike>elementid is invalid syntax, it is trying to mix array and objects but also no brackets or braces.  So that is your error</strike>

Comment: Why do you think `elementid` is invalid syntax?

Comment: Never mind, I was being dumb, I forgot that objects can have keys that are strings and the formatting confused me.  I thought it was a line spilling over not a new line

Comment: `element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf` is the key. Perfectly fine to use a key like this as long as it is within quotes

Comment: A second before you replied I updated my comment realizing my error

Comment: np, I will leave my comment for future reference if other people see this.